# How to list files, symbolic lniks, directories and subdirectories under a mounted volume using C/C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, posix, mount

I want to list files, symbolic links, directories and subdirectories under a mounted volume using C/C++ in Linux.

I have two partitions /dev/sda and /dev/sfdx in my Ubuntu machine.
I want to list all the directories, subdirectories, files and symlinks under it.
How do i achieve it using C/C++.

Currently , i am using below code snippet:

```
struct dirent *direntp;
direntp->d_name
```

to list the directories, files under a directories, but it doesn't work with partitions i.e /dev/sda.

Comment: Partitions like `/dev/sda` are raw filesystem devices.  You should instead be simply walking the directory tree.

Comment: C++ has [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which would do most of that. C, being a totally different language, has no such support in its standard library.

Comment: you'll need to find the mount points of `/dev/sda` and traverse the mount points, `/dev/sda` is a single file

Comment: What is C/C++? Is it ancestor of C++/C#?

Comment: Please choose *one* language and [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].